# Error while downloading WordPress themes

Tags: themes

Installing Theme: Luminescence Lite 1.3.0
Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/luminescence-lite.1.3.0.zip…

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-http-curl.php on line 324

This is the error I am getting when downloading any WordPress themes. Please tell me how to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a problem with slow connection which causes PHP to time out, you can try again later.

The alternative is to download the theme zip file to your computer and upload it from there into the site.

Comment: How do you upload it from there into the site

Comment: Themes admin >> add new >> upload theme (botton next to the title)

Comment: The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Comment: this is the msg which i am receiving while uploading it

Comment: Then you will have to just extract the ZIP and copy the files top the themes directory

Comment: thanks a million tons..you solved my problem due to which i was stuck since a week..I am new to WordPress and for me it was a great problem which you solved.

Answer (score 0):

inside your php.ini file, you need to find two lines:

- max_execution_time = 30
- max_input_time = 60

Try increasing these values.
First try with the max_execution_time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried but it says access is denied